# Instancing multiple objects onto different faces with geo nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

I have a couple of different sided die (d4,6,8,12,20) and I made some number pucks for them. I want to instance them onto the die like I have in the image below with geometry nodes, but I do not want to use 20 different object nodes just to do so. Is there a way to distribute 20 different objects onto the same amount of faces?
[image]

Comment: did u try instance on points but with collection info as instance input?